# Any ideas why this \newcommand{\n}{\lstinline|\n|} macro doesn't work?

Tags: macros, listings, verbatim

So I created a new macro `\newcommand{\n}{\lstinline|\n|}` but for some reason when I use it, all I get is bold 'n' letter and not a nice `\n`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`\lstinline` is a verbatim-like command. It has to do a lot of `\catcode`-magic to disable commands and parse its argument. You can't use it in another command.
https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin.

Answer (score 3):

As Ulrike already posted you can't use verbatim macros or environments inside a macro argument or replacement text. To make `\n` typeset `\n` as verbatim you could use:

```
\newcommand{\n}{\texttt{\string\n}}
```

or use the `verbdef` package:

```
\verbdef\n|\n|
```

Comment: @Peteris: All spaces behind all macros are always ignored. You need to load the `xspace` package to get `xspace` and it must be the very last of the macro replacement text. Alternatively you can write `\n{}` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't your first sentence read "you can't"?

Comment: @lockstep: Uuh, yes of course. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you can use lstinline to define custom commands. I define short commands to include snippets in a specific formal language like this:

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{\lstinline[language=foo]{#1}}
```

If the language `foo` is not defined, you must first define it with

```
\lstdefinelanguage{foo}{ ... }
```

In your code you can then use the custom command like this. Some special characters like `{`,`}`, and `^` must be escaped:

```
Blabla \foo{this is syntax highlighted} blabla,
bla \foo{This contains \{ braces \}}.
```