# How can I create wrapper macro for lstinline?

Tags: macros, listings, verbatim

Using `\lstinline` I can include inline code snippets in a paragraph. I would like to provide a macro that selects formatting, etc, for lstinline so I can just do, say, `\codeinline{snippet}`.

I had implemented this as a short inline, like this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{inlinecode}{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\bfseries}
\lstMakeShortInline[style=inlinecode]~
```

So I could then write `~snippet~`, and that works fine. However, If I need to use `~` in the snippet it doesn't work. The same applies if I change the short inline character to something else. So, I thought of just having a well defined macro, something like:

```
\newcommand\codeinline[1]{\lstinline[style=inlinecode]{#1}}
```

Which also works, except when certain characters are in the snippet. For example, this

```
\codeinline{example-command ~/myfile}
```

does not work because of the `~`. I found a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23387/26269) (which inspired the above `\codeinline` macro) but I don't want to have to escape characters in the snippet, I just want it treated verbatim in the same way as lstinline does. I hope that it is possible because lstinline does it.

It is possible to write a wrapper around `lstinline` that works as well as `lstinline` works ?

Comment: Try not to read in the argument: `\newcommand\codeinline{\lstinline[style=inlinecode]}`

Comment: @cgneider yes, that works. thank you. I'll accept that if you add it as an answer. I'm still learning the nuances of tex.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to avoid to read in the argument with the wrapper macro as this would fix the category codes of the argument and `\lstinline` cannot do its magic anymore. So, here you go:

```
\newcommand\codeinline{\lstinline[style=inlinecode]}
```

This way you can also use the syntax with delimiters:

```
\codeinline+&$%+
```

This works since a macro that has no argument simply is replaced by its definition. So

```
\codeinline+&$%+
```

becomes

```
\lstinline[style=inlinecode]+&$%+
```

which works as intended.

Comment: I would like something similar, but which would enclose the code snippet in quotes.  There's no solution, is there?

Comment: @akim With the `xparse` package you can try `\NewDocumentCommand\mycode{v}{``\lstinline{#1}''}` – I don't know how robust that is, though